# Merging mutiple XAML files into one

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to merge multiple xaml files into one file. I'm looking for advice on how to continue. Currently, I just append xaml code to one file, but without taking care of headers and footers (opening and closing ResourceDictionary tags, and namespace mappings).

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"><SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush">#FFE4F2F9</SolidColorBrush></ResourceDictionary>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"> <some xaml code /> </ResourceDictionary>
```

The only thing that comes to my mind is using regular expressions to extract ResourceDictionary bodies and place them inside one ResourceDictionary tag. However, what would be the best course of action here, and also, caring not to duplicate namespace mappings (like System namespace mapping, that is referenced inside multiple files).

Comment: First law of programming : one shall not parse xml with regex

Comment: Sounds risky. May I ask why do you want to merge them into one because they can be referenced by a merged dictionary?

Comment: I'm trying to establish one big xaml file for testing purposes, and yeah, since regex isn't a good way to go, is there a better way to merge xaml files programatically?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't know how to use merged dictionaries. I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will help you.

Comment: Hi, yes I know about it, however, for testing purposes I want all my merged dictionaries to be merged into one big xaml file.